# Difference between using `add-apt-repository` and adding a link to the sources.list

Tags: ppa, repository

From a user's point of view, they seem equivalent. 
Some programs can be installed via `apt-get install` after adding a link to the `sources.list`.

Others have to be installed by adding a ppa though command line, and as far as I can see, this method doesn't create an entry in the sources.list.

So there must be a technical difference? And, if at all, what is the difference between a PPA and a repository?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding via PPA does add a list. file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, which is sourced by apt so there is a repository there.

The convenience that add-apt-repository provides is that it not only adds the source, it adds the GPG key of the repository so you don't have to do that manually.

Comment: So the only real difference is that adding via PPA adds an entry in form of a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, while adding a repository manually usually works by manipulating the /etc/sources.list as a file? That means that repository-links are saved in those two, different locations?

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Comment: Wish I'd discovered this sooner, I just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 using a clean install. I saved /etc/apt/sources.list but not /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ :-( Now have to re-find and add the repositories for all the software that gives me errors when I try to install it :-(

Comment: I am wondering why aren't both PPA and links get saved into `sources.list.d`? isn't it more organize and unified? why only PPAs get saved to that folder?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a PPA through command line does create an entry.

Command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

After adding the repository it shows up in Ubuntu Software Center:

[image]

Comment: I am testing 12.10 but this is the same for any older version that I know of (well maybe not Breezy ;) )

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I was using the terminal and didn't discover any entry in the /etc/sources.list - file. It seems this is because the entries are made in separate files under /etc/sources.list.d/